# Difference between Suds py3 and Suds Jurko

Tags: python, soap, suds

I new in python 3.
First, I build soap client in python with suds py3. And it's not working.
But after Install suds jurko, it's working now.
What is the difference between suds py3 and suds jurko?

In this article :
https://pypi.org/project/suds-jurko/,
Explain regarding "*temporary fork of the original suds Python*".
Does the original mean suds py3?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just noting this for anyone who comes here looking for information. This came up for me as I have production code that relies upon `suds-jurko 0.6`, and it failed recently.

The `suds-jurko` pypi page [here](https://pypi.org/project/suds-jurko/) says it was intended to be a more current branch off the original `suds` project, but last development was in 2014. The original `suds` project [here](https://pypi.org/project/suds-py3/) is updated as of November 2021, and when I tested it in a virtual environment my code executed successfully. Would recommend updating.

Comment: So for my understanding suds-jurko has been updated to suds-py3 ? The packages with dependencies on suds-jurko will work the same with suds-py3?

Comment: I can't really speak as to whether it is backwards compatible. It's been a year since I was dealing with this, but my recollection is that my code needed little or no modification. I can't speak to whether that is generally true.